# Custom Preference - Time Duration Selection Spinner/Picker for AndroidTV Leanback

Tags: android-tv, leanback

I'm trying to implement a Time Duration Selection Spinner for Android TV using Leanback API. The design I'm looking for is somewhat similar to the Date/Time Selection on an Android TV.

I'm looking for a picker with four columns: month, days, hours and seconds. Basically a time duration setter for a timer app.

I understand that this Preference is not available in the current Leanback API. So, I'm looking for advice on how to customise the design. When I go through the source of a Preference such as `ListPreference`, I don't see any rendering code. So, I'm looking for a nudge in the right direction on how to customise a Preference in Leanback.